# understanding what java 11 dynamic class-file constants

Tags: java, java-11

I'm trying to understand the java 11 (JEP 309) dynamic class-file constants, it looks like an interesting feature.
and I google it, but I didn't find detailed articles (if you know any please share it) I just find this [one](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/08/hands-on-java-constantdynamic.html) by Rafael Winterhalter, but I still have some questions :

1. does this feature will make it possible to extend the types of constants that could be added to the pool (actually the pool could hold primitive and string values- correct me if I'm wrong)
2. in the article it is said that dynamic constant is generated as a result of invoking a **bootstrap** method, and that this method need to be referenced from the class’s constant pool, but how to do it (how to reference this method from class’s constant pool??)??.

Comment: For references - http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/309 . But I am of the opinion that this could be too broad for SO.

Comment: You should narrow your question down to *one actual question*. Currently, it ranges from the first (off-topic) “who will use that” question to the entirely different (still off topic) “how to do it” question. The latter could be brought on topic by combining with the description of an actual implementation attempt from your side.

Comment: Thank you for your responses

Comment: @nullpointer, the official doc is so abstract for me, I don't understand it.

Comment: @Holger, I'm just looking to understand this feature, if you have any resource, or if you could explain it briefly it will be great.

Comment: You did already point to a resource in your question. If that’s not sufficient, you have to describe your actual difficulties, rather than asking such broad questions.

Comment: I updated the question to be clear&clean, but any information about this feature will be helpful

Comment: Why are you interested in it? It is a feature of the JVM, currently not visible to users of the Java language in any of its APIs or language features and you can expose it just by byte code manipulation (as the linked article suggests).

Comment: Ok, that answer one of my question,